# Induced emf vs Potential difference

Tags: electric-fields, voltage, induction, conservative-field, electromagnetic-induction

Let a square conductor frame length $l$, resistance $R$, be pulled out with a constant velocity $\vec{v}$ from a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ perpendicular to plane of the frame, then an emf $\mathscr{E}=Blv$ is produced across the frame.
Since an induced electric field is non conservative while a non induced field is, what should be considered while calculating potential difference between any two given points in an induced field ,or will it be the same as in the latter case?

Comment: For purposes of their *effect*, i.e. forces on charged particles, electric potential and EMF behave exactly the same.

Comment: @garyp I disagree. An EMF around a loop is defined as the source's force per unit charge line integrated around some instantaneous closed loop. Whereas a potential difference is only for electric field sources, and is only well defined for electrostatic fields (so zero around a closed loop) or along path. In this problem there isn't an electric field unless you ate considering Hall voltage from one side to the other (as opposed to one end compared to the other) and that requires your wire have some thickness so the EMF wouldn't have to equal the change in magnetic flux when the wires are thick

Comment: @Timaeus Ok, I accept what you are saying.   But there is another point of view:  the rest frame of the electrons in the wire.  In that frame there is no moving charge.  I think we are forced to conclude that the electrons feel a local electric field in that frame.  I presume the electric field would arise from viewing the magnetic field in frame that's in relative motion.  ("relativistic transformation of B-field").  I'll admit that I haven't worked this out ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let a square conductor frame length **l**, resistance **R**,be pulled out with a constant velocity **v** from a magnetic field **B** perpendicular to plane of the frame .Then an emf **e=Blv** is produced across the frame.

The EMF is around a closed loop. It is equal to the force per unit charge around the loop. So for instance $$\mathscr E=\oint_{\partial S}\left(\vec E+\vec v \times \vec B\right)\cdot d\vec \ell.$$

Your description is a bit vague. If only one part of the wire is moving, that's the part that feels a magnetic force per unit charge. If the whole thing is moving but part is in a magnetic field and the rest is not, then only the parts on the magnetic field feel a magnetic force.

> Since an induced electric field is non conservative

Non conservative electric fields only happen when the magnetic field is changing in time. A motional EMF is from the magnetic force.

> what should be considered while calculating potential difference between any two given points in an induced field ,or will it be the same as in the latter case?

Potentials are a concept from electrostatics, in general they don't exist and in general if you try to use a son called voltmeter the reading will be affected by how much magnetic flux is going through the voltmeter and how much that flux is changing. Instead you often want to be computing the force per unit charge line integrated along the direction of the loop because that is often the analog of voltage.