# How to find potential difference between two points in a loop in case of motional emf?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Given below is a question in my physics textbook.

> A rectangular frame of wire abcd has dimensions 32 cm×8.0 cm and a total resistance of 2.0 Ω. It is pulled out of a magnetic field B=0.02 T by applying a force of 3.2×10
> −5
> N (figure). It is found that the frame moves with constant speed.
> Find (a) this constant speed, (b) the emf induced in the loop, (c) the potential difference between the points a and b and (d) the potential difference between the points c and d.

> [image]

My problem is with parts c) and d).

I am not sure how to approach the problem. A mechanical way would be to just replace each segments of wire with  appropriate resistors, add a battery to section *ba*, and then solve for potential difference by using Kirchoff's Voltage Law. But I also know that the induced EMF in the loop results from flux change, and so the EMF results from Non-Conservative Electric Fields. But since KVL cannot be used in presence of Non-Conservative Fields and the concept of potential difference is not applicable in case of induced EMF, I am not sure if the problem can be solved.

Is something wrong with my reasoning? And if yes, then I would appreciate some enlightenment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the loop is moving with moving a velocity $v$. The magnetic flux through the loop is $\Phi_B=B\cdot(xl)$ where $l$ is the length of segment $ab$ and $x$ is the length of the part of segment $bc$ which is inside the magnetic field. Naturally $\dot{x}=v.$ So induced EMF in the loop is
$$|V|=\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}=Bl\frac{dx}{dt}=Blv$$
Current in the circuit is
$$I=\frac{Blv}{R}$$
The net magnetic force acting on the loop is the same as a magnetic force acting on the segment $ab$ since the forces on segment $bc$ and $ad$ cancel each other out which should be equal to the applied pulling force $F_{a}$ because the loop is moving with constant velocity. By equating the magnetic force on the loop and $F_a$ you should be able to find out $v$ which can be used to finding the net EMF and the current in the loop. $V_{cd}$ can be found by finding the resistance of the segment $cd$ and applying ohm's law.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that by problem was not with how to solve the problem, but can the problem be solved? You used flux change to calculate EMF and current. But if there is flux change, that indicates a time-varying magnetic field, which indicates a non-conservative electric field. The concept of potential difference is not valid in presence of non-conservative electric field. So how can the question ask us to find potential difference?    https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210931/induced-emf-vs-potential-difference